# ¿Por qué la consulta me repite 2 veces los datos? SQL, PHP

Tags: php, sql

Pues bien, lo que sucede es que debido a que la consulta que debo hacer es relacional y los datos de las personas estan en otra base de datos y todo va bien excepto cuando intento buscar alguien que tiene casi el mismo apellido como por ejemplo: rodriguez, se supone que me debe de mostrar uno por cada persona que tenga ese apellido, pero en vez de eso me muestra dos veces la misma persona ej:

julanito perez rodriguez
julanito perez rodriguez
camilo gomez rodriguez
camilo gomez rodriguez
francisco rodriguez
francisco rodriguez

```html
<?php

$consulta = $pdo->prepare('SELECT 
TPI.nombre, 
TPI.apellido 

FROM alumnos_en_actividad TPP INNER JOIN proyecto TPLI 
INNER JOIN bd_informacion.info_estudiantes TPI 
ON TPP.id_alumnos = TPI.id_alumnos 
WHERE TPP.proyecto =:proyecto AND TPLI.proyecto =:proyecto AND 

TPLI.carnet =:carnet AND 
TPLI.nombre_proyecto=:nombre_proyecto AND
TPLI.codigo1=:codigo1 AND
TPLI.id_encargado=:id_encargado AND 
TPI.nombre LIKE :buscarPorNombre OR
TPI.apellido LIKE :buscarPorNombre 
');

    
   
      $query->execute([
        'proyecto'=>1110101,
        'carnet'=>'12', 
        'nombre_proyecto'=>'especial navidad',
        'codigo1'=>606060, 
        'id_encargado'=>5,
        'buscarPorNombre'=>'%rodriguez%'

      ]);

      $caja=[];
      while($row = $query->fetch()){

        
        $alm=$row['nombre'];
        $alm=$row['apellido'];
   
        array_push($caja, $alm); 
      }
      
      return $caja;

?>
```

Qué debo eliminar o modificar?

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos un `var_dump($caja);` para ver cómo están organizados los datos? Es probable que cambiando esto no recibas datos duplicados: `while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){`, el problema podría ser que al no especificar un *fetch style* te esté organizando los datos como lo hace `fetch` por defecto, con un índice numérico y otro asociativo, lo que hace que tengas dos veces los mismos datos organizados de diferente forma. Revisa [lo que dice el Manual de PHP al respecto](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente pq en el primer join no tienes la condición para el join así que hay una *multiplicacion vectorial* y eso podría producir resultados repetidos.

Comment: se pueden hacer dos WHERE en el mismo?

Comment: Podrías poner más condiciones en el where.... pero creo que no es correcto. Idealmente deberías colocar la condición  para unir las dos primeras tablas en el join.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el problema y es que me faltó los parentesis al hacer la búsquedad, les dejo la solución abajo

```html
<?php

$consulta = $pdo->prepare('SELECT 
TPI.nombre, 
TPI.apellido 

FROM alumnos_en_actividad TPP INNER JOIN proyecto TPLI 
INNER JOIN bd_informacion.info_estudiantes TPI 
ON TPP.id_alumnos = TPI.id_alumnos 
WHERE TPP.proyecto =:proyecto AND TPLI.proyecto =:proyecto AND 

//Aquí abajo es donde me faltaron los parentesis
(TPLI.carnet =:carnet AND 
TPLI.nombre_proyecto=:nombre_proyecto AND
TPLI.codigo1=:codigo1 AND
TPLI.id_encargado=:id_encargado AND 
TPI.nombre LIKE :buscarPorNombre OR
TPI.apellido LIKE :buscarPorNombre) 

');

    
   
      $query->execute([
        'proyecto'=>1110101,
        'carnet'=>'12', 
        'nombre_proyecto'=>'especial navidad',
        'codigo1'=>606060, 
        'id_encargado'=>5,
        'buscarPorNombre'=>'%rodriguez%'

      ]);

      $caja=[];
      while($row = $query->fetch()){

        
        $alm=$row['nombre'];
        $alm=$row['apellido'];
   
        array_push($caja, $alm); 
      }
      
      return $caja;

?>
```

Comment: Y nosotros como podriamos haber adivinado eso? sin ver datos, tablas ni nada???